# Curl Windows Cmd, HTTP2 Pseudo Headers Using

Tags: curl

I need use http2 pseudo headers on curl command line,
:path
:scheme
:authority
:method
headers

curl version: 8.6.0

Build: 8.6.0_1
System: Windows x64

Cmd command line

I need to use these headers, otherwise the request sends a garbled response or I encounter problems. I want to send the same way as in Chrome.

my command:

```
curl --request GET https://example.com/test -H ":method: GET" --http2 -k
```

and tested tried --http2-prior-knowledge
not worked

Im entered any pseudo header but Curl removing method header
Any method?
impossible?
Or any python or nodejs (javascript) module? supporting http/2&3/ and pseudo headers

I don't have to use curl.
Any working modules on py or js?

Isn't there an http module where I can be completely free for all request settings?